# Troubleshooting why PHP won't create a file

Tags: php, permissions

I have an issue with a server and I don't know how to even start troubleshooting the problem.

I am using [Freshizer](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/freshizer-custom-wordpress-image-resizer-with-cache/67082) which basically takes the users browser resolution and creates a copy of the images on the site that is suitable for that specific resolution. The idea is it saves on bandwidth, only ever downloading/displaying the smallest sized image necessary.

Anyway, I'm using it with a custom WordPress theme and it works perfectly on my XAMPP installation and also on my rented server but as soon as I transfer it all onto the site owners server it seems that freshizer doesn't create the image copies (everything else works fine).

I'm guessing the issue is with some kind of permissions to write? The folder/file permissions in the new server are the same as those on my rented server and they are both running Linux too. How can I confirm (or refute) this theory? Or how do I go about narrowing down the issue? ... as an extra, how do I fix it?

Comment: Just checked source of Freshizer, it is using imagepng, imagegif functions which are dependent on GD library. Is GD library enable on your server? you can chk it via phpinfo

Comment: I think so, in phpinfo under 'gd' it has an option of GD Support = Enabled. In fact the whole table under 'gd' matches the settings on my server (where the script works fine)